# How to find a specific occurrence of a string inside of a string

Tags: java, string

The problem is this, I'm trying to find and get only one occurrence of a string, when the only way I can get one is by using a keyword that occurs multiple times.

> Ex. 4 potato, **4 (string I want)**, 4 house, 4 car

How do I only get the string I want, when I can't type in any keywords that the string might contain.

Imagine it as trying to take only one paragraph out of an essay.

I've tried the stringy.replaceAll(Str1, Str2); variable, but to no avail.  All that happens is I replace all of the string (go figure with a name like replace all)

```
package com.donovan.cunningham;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class EssayCreator {
//Creating varz
    private static String[] lf = {"happy", "sad", "unhappy", "atractive",
        "fast", "lazy"};
    private static String[] op = {"estatic", "melhencohly", "depressed", 
        "alluring", "swift", "lackadaisical"};
    private static String pF = "   ";
    private static String temp[];
    private static String conv = "   ";
    private static String comm = ", ";
    private static Random random = new Random();
    private ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void Converter(String in) {
        in = in.replace(comm, conv);
        for (int i = 0; i < lf.length; i++){    
            in = in.replace(lf[i], op[i]);
        }
        in = in.replace(conv, comm);
        //int rand = random.nextInt(in.indexOf(pF));
        for (int i = 0; i < in.indexOf(pF); i++){
            /*
                Where I want to get an exact string of an essay
                I'd convert pF to conv, and then remove the paragraph to 
                change the order
            } */
        }

        CreateGUI.output.setText(in);
        Sound.stopSound();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I am very confused by your question. Would you mind walking through an example of what you want to do? It sounds like you are looking for regular expressions. They will allow you to search for patterns in a string. You can look into the Matcher class for java. I believe there is a method called replaceFirst that might get you on the right path

Comment: Find the second "4" using String indexOf.  Find the third "4".  Your substring is between the first position (the second "4") and the third position.  As an alternative, String split on the comma + space, then get your substring from the second part.

Comment: What is your query exactly, can you be more clear?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear though. You want (1) to find the most occurrence string which you don't know or you want (2) to replace the occurrence string that you know?

The most naive way to do (1) is to chop your text by space and put them in a string-to-integer HashMap to calculate the most occurrence string. You can also scan this HashMap to find all the N-occurence strings

For (2), supposed that you already know which key string you want to find, you can apply indexOf(String str, int fromIndex) in String recursively as followed:

```
int occurenceCount = 0;
String input = "Here is your text with key_word1, key_word2, ...etc"; 
StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
int index = input.indexOf("key_word");
int copiedIndex = 0;

for(index>0)
{
  output.append(input.substring(copiedIndex, index));
  occurenceCount++;
  if(occurenceCount==4) //Find 4th occurrence and replaced it with "new_key_word"
  {
    output.append("new_key_word")
  }
  else
  {
    output.append("key_word")
  }
  copiedIndex = index+("key_word".length);
  index = input.indexOf("key_word", index+("key_word".length));
  if(index==-1)
    break;
}
```

Ref: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String,%20int)

Not sure if I had answered your question though...

Answer (score 0):

I've combed through your code and tried running it with a use case I made from the cryptic info you've given.  As folks above are saying, it's not clear what you're trying to accomplish.  Typically regex is your friend when trying to do more complex string pattern matching if String's built in methods are not enough.  Try googling 'pattern match string in paragraph regex java' or something to that effect. Meanwhile, I've added some comments to your code which might help with making this question more clear.  Happy to help if I can better understand what you're trying to do.  See code and comments below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class EssayCreator {
    // Creating varz
    private static String[] lf = { "happy", "sad", "unhappy", "atractive",
        "fast", "lazy" };
    private static String[] op = { "estatic", "melhencohly", "depressed",
        "alluring", "swift", "lackadaisical" };
    private static String pF = "   ";
    private static String temp[];
    private static String conv = "   ";
    private static String comm = ", ";
    private static Random random = new Random();
    private List<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Bradley D: Just some side notes here: 
    // Don't capitalize method names and don't use nouns.
    // They're not class names or constructors. Changed Converter to convert. It'd also be good to
    // stipulate what you are converting, i.e. convertMyString to make this a
    // little more intuitive
    public static void convert(String in) {
        /*
         * Bradley D: First, you are replacing all commas following by a space
         * with 3 spaces. Be good to know why you doin that?
         */
        in = in.replace(comm, conv);
        for (int i = 0; i < lf.length; i++) {
            in = in.replace(lf[i], op[i]);
        }
        /*
         * Bradley D: Now you are replacing the 3 spaces with a comma and a
         * space again??
         */
        in = in.replace(conv, comm);

        // Bradley D: Not really sure what you are trying to iterate through
        // here. in.indexOf(pF) is -1
        // for the use case I've created for you with the text below (what did I
        // miss?)...
        // Perhaps you're trying to find the first place in your essay where pF
        // (3 spaces) occurs....
        // but you've already reconverted your 3 spaces back to a comma and
        // single space, so I'm getting even more lost here....
        // int rand = random.nextInt(in.indexOf(pF));
        for (int i = 0; i < in.indexOf(pF); i++) {
            /*
             * Bradley D: What is pF?? It appears to be the same as comm...
             */
            /*
             * Where I want to get an exact string of an essay I'd convert pF to
             * conv, and then remove the paragraph to change the order }
             */

            // Bradley D: Ok, so if you can make this question clear, I'll give it a shot here
        }
        // Bradley D: Commenting this out since it was not included
        // CreateGUI.output.setText(in);
        // Sound.stopSound();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EssayCreator ec = new EssayCreator();
        String essay = "Let's see if we find the desired string in here.  "
            + "Are we happy? Nope, we're not happy.  Who's happy? What does happiness mean anyway? "
            + "I'd be very happy if this question we're more clear, but let's give it a go anyway. Maybe "
            + "we're lazy, and that's not attractive, thus rendering us unhappy and lackadasical... jk! "
            + "So hey man... why are you replacing all of the commas with spaces?  "
            + "Can you put comments in your code? What is pF? "
            + "Also you should not capitalize method names.  They should be in camelCase and they should not "
            + "be nouns like Converter, which makes them look like a constructor.  Methods represent "
            + "an action taken, so a verb to describe them is standard practice. "
            + "So use convert, but what are you converting? convertString?? convertWords? "
            + "Anyway, making your method names intuitive would be helpful to anyone trying to understand "
            + "the code.";
        ec.convert(essay);
    }
}
```